# Excel Pivot Table - how exclude values column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table with products split by price ranges, buy requests from Shop and Online, and pieces in Stock.

When I create a Pivot Table from my table I'd like to exclude the Sum of REQ SHOP from the columns, but keeping it in the TOTAL. Is there a way to do it that is not hiding the columns...?

Thanks!
A-

[image: Table]

[image: Pivot Table]

Comment: I don't think so, not through pivot tables.

Comment: Try using PowerPivot and Measures instead.